# Magento 2 - Flushing Cache does flush cache on other project!

Tags: magento2

I created a clone of my live project and named it `live_clone`.
Then I changed the database credentials in `app/etc/env.php` to my new live_clone database and
imported the live database to it.

Then I opened the database with phpmyadmin and changed the BASE URL's to the live_clone domain.

I did this often and it always worked flawlessly.

Then I changed to deployment mode "production".

However, if I execute `php bin/magento cache:flush` on live_clone, then the cache is getting flushed for my live project instead of for the project live_clone. If I execute `grunt clean` on live_clone then users get redirected to live_clone instead of live!

What is going on?

Comment: where do you keep your cache? Redis/ files?

Comment: Good question! Yes, I am using Redis. It might still use the redis from live hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that you are not using the Redis connection in app/etc/env.php `cache` key for both `default` and `page_cache` sub-keys.

Comment: Do you know if I can create a new Redis Database for `live_clone`? Or can I only use redis for the `live` project and I need to disable it for `live_clone` ?

Comment: ↑ I just changed the database numbers everywhere, now it seems to work!

Comment: Glad to hear this! Regarding your question, I would totally go with having separate redis instances. Why? because say you are debugging something and clear the cache directly using `redis flushall` - this command will flush all databases and you can accidentally clear the prod cache. you could theoretically use a diff database if you use only magento cache cleaning options, but i am not sure how this behaves when you use *Flush Cache Storage* button, (it doesn't care about tags, probably will delete your prod cache as well).